# how to change the element of a string without reset the whole string

Tags: python

Here is an example

```
n = 1
stringA = 'I have' + str(n) + 'apple'
print(stringA)
> I have 1 apple
```

How can I do this without building a function around it

```
n = 2
print(stringA)
> I have 2 apple
```

Comment: There's no reason to write a function for that; just put it all right in the `print` statement. `print("I have " + str(n) + " apple")` No use making up new variables just to print them.

Comment: kindall, hi, sorry I wasn't clear back there. 'print' the string is just for demonstration only. I was going to assign the string as one of the function parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want to use a function? Fundamentally this isn't possible, since you cannot "change an element in  string", since `str` objects are immutable. You'll have to re-assign a new string to `stringA` somehow. But making a function for this is easy and more robust, anyway:

```
>>> make_string = "I have {} apple".format
>>> make_string(2)
'I have 2 apple'
>>> make_string(3)
'I have 3 apple'
>>> make_string(4)
'I have 4 apple'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't want to use function is because I have several strings look like this and I don't want to build functions for every one of them. However, if there is a more robust way to build a function that is as general as the example you showed above I will be more than happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite clear and simple:

```
>>> s = 'I have %s apple'
>>> print(s % 5)
I have 5 apple
>>> print(s % 3)
I have 3 apple
>>> n = 2
>>> print(s % n)
I have 2 apple
```